# 502 Bad Gateway and 503 Service Unavailable - But it's Inconsistent

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, api

I have this code, once you enter a persons name and job title, it goes through a list of different tables and makes records of them, in which it will be saving data from some later forms.  The problem is it will only create some of the records, the others it gives me either a 502 or 503 error. And it's inconsistent.  It may create 3 or 4 of the records as expected, but a different 3 or 4 each time.  The 502 and 503 errors happen on different calls each time.  So I know the code itself actually works, in fact it works flawlessly on my local build.  But in my production build, this happens.

I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this, so I'm happy to hear ideas on that as well. The only reason I have multiple tables is there are about 200 fields on our form, and mySql wouldn't let me put it all together in one.

Here is the code:

```
createQuestions() {
    fetch(
      API_URL + `/interview/create/questions/${this.state.lastEmployeeId}`,
      {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          lastEmployeeId: this.state.lastEmployeeId,
          table: "audit_general",
        }),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      }
    )
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error();
        }
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      .then(
        fetch(
          API_URL + `/interview/create/questions/${this.state.lastEmployeeId}`,
          {
            method: "PUT",
            body: JSON.stringify({
              lastEmployeeId: this.state.lastEmployeeId,
              table: "audit_culture",
            }),
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          }
        )
          .then((res) => {
            if (!res.ok) {
              throw new Error();
            }
            return res.json();
          })
          .then((data) => console.log(data))
          .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      )
      .then(
        fetch(
          API_URL + `/interview/create/questions/${this.state.lastEmployeeId}`,
          {
            method: "PUT",
            body: JSON.stringify({
              lastEmployeeId: this.state.lastEmployeeId,
              table: "audit_performance",
            }),
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          }
        )
          .then((res) => {
            if (!res.ok) {
              throw new Error();
            }
            return res.json();
          })
          .then((data) => console.log(data))
          .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      )
      .then(
        fetch(
          API_URL + `/interview/create/questions/${this.state.lastEmployeeId}`,
          {
            method: "PUT",
            body: JSON.stringify({
              lastEmployeeId: this.state.lastEmployeeId,
              table: "audit_policies",
            }),
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          }
        )
          .then((res) => {
            if (!res.ok) {
              throw new Error();
            }
            return res.json();
          })
          .then((data) => console.log(data))
          .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      )
      .then(
        fetch(
          API_URL + `/interview/create/questions/${this.state.lastEmployeeId}`,
          {
            method: "PUT",
            body: JSON.stringify({
              lastEmployeeId: this.state.lastEmployeeId,
              table: "audit_risk",
            }),
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          }
        )
          .then((res) => {
            if (!res.ok) {
              throw new Error();
            }
            return res.json();
          })
          .then((data) => console.log(data))
          .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      )
      .then(
        fetch(
          API_URL + `/interview/create/questions/${this.state.lastEmployeeId}`,
          {
            method: "PUT",
            body: JSON.stringify({
              lastEmployeeId: this.state.lastEmployeeId,
              table: "audit_strategy",
            }),
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          }
        )
          .then((res) => {
            if (!res.ok) {
              throw new Error();
            }
            return res.json();
          })
          .then((data) => console.log(data))
          .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      )
      .then(
        fetch(
          API_URL + `/interview/create/questions/${this.state.lastEmployeeId}`,
          {
            method: "PUT",
            body: JSON.stringify({
              lastEmployeeId: this.state.lastEmployeeId,
              table: "audit_rewards",
            }),
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          }
        )
          .then((res) => {
            if (!res.ok) {
              throw new Error();
            }
            return res.json();
          })
          .then((data) => console.log(data))
          .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      )
      .then(
        fetch(
          API_URL + `/interview/create/questions/${this.state.lastEmployeeId}`,
          {
            method: "PUT",
            body: JSON.stringify({
              lastEmployeeId: this.state.lastEmployeeId,
              table: "audit_workforce",
            }),
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          }
        )
          .then((res) => {
            if (!res.ok) {
              throw new Error();
            }
            return res.json();
          })
          .then((data) => console.log(data))
          .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      );
  }
}
```

There are the errors I get:

```
List.js:401 PUT https://ppr-team.com/api/interview/create/questions/41 502 (Bad Gateway)

List.js:443 PUT https://ppr-team.com/api/interview/create/questions/41 502 (Bad Gateway)

List.js:422 PUT https://ppr-team.com/api/interview/create/questions/41 502 (Bad Gateway)

List.js:464 PUT https://ppr-team.com/api/interview/create/questions/41 503 (Service Unavailable)

List.js:485 PUT https://ppr-team.com/api/interview/create/questions/41 503 (Service Unavailable)
```

I am not sure where to track this down.

Answer (score 0):

The server is being mean, you should check to see if it's running correctly and properly configured. Not much else really, 500 range means the server is doing something wrong, either that or it's a bad api that doesn't use the correct status codes.

Comment: I added some columns to several of my tables.  Any change that could have caused some of this?